# AWK array seems to empty itself?

Tags: arrays, awk

I am trying to learn awk by solving code puzzles. I am trying to read several "grids" of integers (representing bingo boards as per https://adventofcode.com/2021/day/4) into a three-dimensional awk array. An example "grid" can look like this:

```
22 13 17 11  0
 8  2 23  4 24
21  9 14 16  7
 6 10  3 18  5
 1 12 20 15 19
```

And there are several of these in a longer input file. After reading each line into an array `rows` I am attempting to organize the numbers into this multi dimensional array called `boards`. Here is my example code:

```
{
  b = 0
  for (i in rows) {
    split(rows[i], nums, " ")
    for (j in nums) {
      r = i % 5
      n = j - 1
      boards[b][r][n] = nums[j]
      print b, r, n, nums[j], boards[b][r][n]
    }
    if (i%5==0)
      ++b
  }
  print boards[0][1][1]
}
```

Notice the debug printout `print b, r, n, nums[j], boards[b][r][n]` which indeed outputs the correct values for `boards[b][r][n]` on that row:

```
0 0 0 22 22
0 0 1 13 13
0 0 2 17 17
```

Etc. This seems to verify that the multi dimensional array gets written properly. Yet on the final line of the example code, the output is instead empty. I have tried using the form `boards[b, r, n]` for the array as well with the exact same result. Obviously there's something I'm not quite understanding here. Any help is appreciated. Full code for reproducibility:

```
# === ex.txt ===
7,4,9,5,11,17,23,2,0,14,21,24,10,16,13,6,15,25,12,22,18,20,8,19,3,26,1

22 13 17 11  0
 8  2 23  4 24
21  9 14 16  7
 6 10  3 18  5
 1 12 20 15 19

 3 15  0  2 22
 9 18 13 17  5
19  8  7 25 23
20 11 10 24  4
14 21 16 12  6

14 21 17 24  4
10 16 15  9 19
18  8 23 26 20
22 11 13  6  5
 2  0 12  3  7
```

```
# === solve.awk ===
BEGIN {
  r = 0
}

{
  if (NR == 1)
    split($0, draws, "")
  else if (NR != 2 && (NR-3)%6 != 5)
    rows[r++] = $0
}

END {
  b = 0
  for (i in rows) {
    split(rows[i], nums, " ")
    for (j in nums) {
      r = i % 5
      n = j - 1
      boards[b][r][n] = nums[j]
      print b, r, n, nums[j], boards[b][r][n]
    }
    if (i%5==0)
      ++b
  }
  print boards[0][1][1]
}
```

I run this with `awk -f solve.awk ex.txt`. `awk --version` outputs `GNU Awk 5.1.1, API: 3.1 (GNU MPFR 4.1.0-p13, GNU MP 6.2.1)` as its first line. Thank you!

Comment: I see no `0 1 1 ...` line from your for loop...

Comment: one small hint : you can split( ) directly into a middle dimension of an existing MDR, and not affect the data in the rest of the array. Unfortunately, i'm not aware of ways of use a single split( ) call and split out 3 dimensions, for instance. Another hint about old school emulated MDR of array[ i , j , k ] - it's just based on whatever the SUBSEP is at any moment of time, not at time of initial array creation.  So existing keys *can* be made pseudo-MDR by changing SUBSEP to one that already splits the keys you  want, e.g. using " " or "=" or ":" as SUBSEP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are incrementing `b` at the end of the first iteration of your `for (i in rows)` loop because `i == 0 ==> i%5 == 0`, while you want to do it at the end of the 5th iteration. Try `if (i%5 == 4) ++b`.

Note that as you use GNU awk you could simplify all this. When the record separator (`RS`) is the empty string the records are separated by empty lines (one record per board):

```
$ awk -v RS='' '
  NR>1 {
    a[NR-2][1]; split($0, a[NR-2]);
  }
  END {
    for(b in a) for(r in a[b])
      boards[b][int((r-1)/5)][(r-1)%5] = a[b][r];
    for(b in boards) for(r in boards[b]) for(n in boards[b][r])
      print b, r, n, boards[b][r][n]
  }' ex.txt 
0 0 0 22
0 0 1 13
0 0 2 17
0 0 3 11
0 0 4 0
0 1 0 8
...
```

Comment: This was exactly it! Thank you for the simplified code, I will look it over tonight.